# Implementing 3rd Order Tensor in OpenFOAM-v1612+

Tags: tensor, higher-order-functions, openfoam

I am using c++ code for OpenFOAM 1612+.

I want to implement 3rd order tensors `UUU` and `rhoUUU`.

As I understood in OpenFOAM a `volTensorField` is a field of second-order tensors not for higher.

So that, it is always throwing an error. I have tried different ways, but I am not too experienced in OpenFOAM or C++.

Do you have any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Thank you